# Prove that triangle is right if $s=2R+r$, where $R$, $r$, $s$ are its circumradius, inradius, and semiperimeter

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

> Let $R$ and $r$ be circumradius and inradius respectively of a triangle with semiperimeter $s$. Prove that it is right if $$s=2R+r$$

It is not hard to find $$s = {a\over \sin \alpha} + (s-a)\tan{\alpha \over 2}$$
Labeling $x=\tan{\alpha\over 2}$ we have $$(2s-a)x^2-2sx +a=0 $$ which has solution $x=1$ and $x= \displaystyle{a\over b+c}$. If $x=1$ we are done else $${a\over b+c} = \tan{\alpha\over 2} = {r\over s-a}\hspace{2cm} (1)$$
We can do the same for other two angles and if some is right then we are done, else we have also
$${b\over c+a} = \tan{\beta\over 2} = {r\over s-b}\hspace{2cm} (2)$$ and $${c\over a+b} = \tan{\gamma\over 2} = {r\over s-c}\hspace{2cm} (3)$$

Multiplying all equations (1),(2) and (3) we have
$$s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)abc = r^3s(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$
$$S^2abc = r^3s(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$
$$sabc = r(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)$$
$$sbc = (a+b)(s-a)(c+a)$$
$$(a+b+c)bc = (a(a+b+c)+bc)(b+c-a)$$
$$ abc+(b+c)bc = a(b^2+c^2+2bc-a^2)+ bc(b+c)-abc$$
$$ 0 = a(b^2+c^2-a^2)$$ and we are done.

Is there more nice synthetic solution without trigonometry?

Comment: see [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1343828p7308666) obtained using [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/)

Comment: A better reference : see theorem 3 [here](https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2018volume18/FG201825.pdf) obtained from this rich [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_triangle_inequalities)

Comment: I found pure geometric solution to this one. It a shame I can not reward my self. :)

Comment: Please write this solution. I will be happy to upvote it.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ihave posted a solution. Have you see it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A$ be the area of the triangle. Note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos {\alpha}
= {} & \frac{b^2 + c^2 - a^2}{2bc}
\\
= {} & \frac{(b + c)^2 - a^2}{2bc} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{(b + c - a)(b + c + a)}{2bc} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{(2s - 2a)(2s)}{2bc} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{2s(s - a)}{bc} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{2sr(s - a)}{rbc} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{2A(s - a)}{rbc} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{2Aa(s - a)}{rabc} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{2Aa(s - a)}{4ARr} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{a(s - a)}{2Rr} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{2R (s - 2R \sin {\alpha}) \sin {\alpha} }{2Rr} - 1
\\
= {} & \frac{(s - 2R \sin {\alpha}) \sin {\alpha} }{r} - 1.
\end{aligned}
$$
Hence
$$
r(1 + \cos {\alpha}) = (s - 2R \sin {\alpha}) \sin {\alpha},
$$
which is
$$
r \cdot 2\cos {\alpha \over 2} \cos {\alpha \over 2}
= (s - 2R \sin {\alpha}) \cdot 2\cos {\alpha \over 2} \sin {\alpha \over 2},
$$
which is
$$
r \cdot 2\cos {\alpha \over 2} \sin {\alpha \over 2}
= (s - 2R \sin {\alpha}) \cdot 2\sin {\alpha \over 2} \sin {\alpha \over 2},
$$
which is
$$
r \sin {\alpha}
= (s - 2R \sin {\alpha}) (1 - \cos {\alpha}),
$$
which is
$$
\sin {\alpha} = \frac{s (1 - \cos {\alpha})}{(2R + r) - 2R\cos {\alpha}}.
$$
Hence
$$
r(1 + \cos {\alpha}) = \left( s - 2R \frac{s (1 - \cos {\alpha})}{(2R + r) - 2R\cos {\alpha}} \right)
\frac{s (1 - \cos {\alpha})}{(2R + r) - 2R\cos {\alpha}},
$$
which is
$$
4R^2 \cos^3 {\alpha} - 4R (R + r) \cos^2 {\alpha} + (s^2 + r^2 - 4R^2) \cos {\alpha} - (s^2 - (2R + r)^2) = 0.
$$

---

Hence $\cos {\alpha}$, $\cos {\beta}$, $\cos {\gamma}$ are the roots of the eqaution
$$
4R^2 x^3 - 4R (R + r) x^2 + (s^2 + r^2 - 4R^2)x - (s^2 - (2R + r)^2) = 0.
$$
Hence
$$
\cos {\alpha} \cos {\beta} \cos {\gamma}
= \frac{s^2 - (2R + r)^2}{4R^2} = 0.
$$
Hence one of $\cos {\alpha}$, $\cos {\beta}$, $\cos {\gamma}$ must be zero.

Comment: Brilliant answer! You may also note that the final equation in your answer is actually a *relatively* well known trigonometric identity, even proven on MSE before

Answer (score 5):

There is an identity concerning the product of cosines of angles $A, B, C$ with $s,r, R$:

> In a triangle $ABC,$ we have $$\cos A \cos B \cos C= \frac{s^2-(2R+r)^2}{4R^2}.$$

It is being shown here:

[Showing $\cos A\cos B\cos C=\frac{s^2-(2R+r)^2}{4R^2}$ and $\cos A+\cos B+\cos C=1+\frac rR$ in $\triangle ABC$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4019680/showing-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c-fracs2-2rr24r2-and-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c?rq=1)

and additional reference:

[How to prove that $\frac{r}{R}+1=\cos A+\cos B+\cos C$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734395/how-to-prove-that-fracrr1-cos-a-cos-b-cos-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Hence, in any triangle $ABC$,
$$\triangle ABC \textrm{ is }\begin{cases}\textrm{obtuse $\quad \quad $ if $s<2R+r$} \\ \textrm{right $\quad \quad \ \ \ $ if $s=2R+r$} \\ \textrm{acute $\quad \quad \ \ $ if $s>2R+r.$} \end{cases}$$

Answer (score 3):

We have $$a+b+c=2s\tag1$$
$$abc=4rRs\tag2$$

Let us represent $ab+bc+ca$ by $r,R$ and $s$.

Representing the area of the triangle in two ways, we have
$$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}=rs$$
(LHS is [Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula))

Squaring the both sides and dividing by $s$, we get
$$(s - a)(s - b)(s - c) = r^2s$$
i.e.
$$s^3 - (a + b + c)s^2 + (ab + bc + ca)s - abc = r^2s$$

Substituting $(1)(2)$, we obtain
$$ ab + bc + ca = s^2 + r^2 + 4rR\tag3$$

So, if $s=2R+r$, we have
$$a+b+c=4R+2r\tag4$$
$$ab+bc+ca=4R^2+2r^2+8rR\tag5$$
$$abc=4rR(2R+r)\tag6$$

From $(4)(5)(6)$, we see that $a,b,c$ are the roots of
$$x^3-(4R+2r)x^2+(4R^2+2r^2+8Rr)x-4rR(2R+r)=0$$
which can be written as
$$(x-2R)\bigg(x^2-(2r+2R)x+4rR+2r^2\bigg)=0$$

Since one of $a,b,c$ is equal to $2R$, the triangle is right.$\ \ \blacksquare$

---

**Added** :

I'm going to add another proof which might be "less algebraic".

It is sufficient to prove that if $\triangle{ABC}$ is not right, then $s\not=2R+r$.

*Proof* :

We may suppose that $\angle{ACB}\lt 90^\circ$.

For fixed $R,AB$ and $\angle{ACB}$, let us consider $s-2R-r$.

[image]

$s-2R-r$ is of the form $f(x)=px+q$ where $p>0,q$ are constants and $x=CA+CB$ because we have
$$\begin{align}s-2R-r&=\frac{AB+x}{2}-2R-\bigg(\frac{AB+x}{2}-AB\bigg)\tan\frac C2
\\\\&=\underbrace{\frac{1-\tan\frac C2}{2}}_{\text{positive constant}}x+\underbrace{\frac{AB}{2}\bigg(1+\tan\frac C2\bigg)-2R}_{\text{constant}}:=f(x)\end{align}$$

Let $P,Q$ be points on the circumcircle such that $\triangle{PAB},\triangle{QAB}$ are right where $f(PA+PB)=f(QA+QB)=0$.

Now, let us consider an ellipse $E$ whose foci are $A,B$ passing through $P,Q$.

[image]

We can see that if $\triangle{ABC}$ is not right, then $x\not=PA+PB$.

Since $f(x)$ is of the form $px+q$, we can say that if $x\not=PA+PB$, then $f(x)\not=f(PA+PB)=0$, i.e. $s-2R-r\not=0$.$\ \ \blacksquare$

(In the proof, I used $r=(s-c)\tan\frac C2$. If I find a proof without using trigonometry, I'll post it.)

Comment: Yes, thanks, but again this is just algebraic solution.

Comment: @nonuser : I added another proof which might be "less algebraic". I have been tried to avoid using trigonometry, but to no avail. If I find a proof without using trigonometry, I'll post it.

Answer (score 2):

Reflect $A$ across circumcenter $S$ into $A'$. And let $D$ be a midpoint of arc $AB$ which does not contain $C$. Then $A'D$ and $CD$ are angle bisectors of $\angle AA'B$ and $\angle ACB$.

*Lemma*: Circle with center at $D$ and radius $DA=DB$ cut angle bisector at incenter of a triangle. (This should be well know fact and easy to prove.)

Similarity of colored triangles give us $${r'\over r} = {s'-c\over s-c}$$ and since triangle $AA'B$ is right we have $s' = 2R+r'$. Eliminating $r$ we get $$ (2R-c)(s-s')=0$$ so if $c=2R$ we are done else $s=s'$. But then $r'=r$ and so $II'$ is parallel to $AB$ and thus cyclic quadrilater $ABI'I$ must be isosceles. But then $ABC$ and $ABA'$ are congruent and we are done.

[image]

Comment: [+1] Elegant ! I was puzzled at first by your use of $s'=2R+r'$ but I remembered that it is a necessary condition...

Comment: Yes, but that is a trivial to see. Also you can see the proof of that fact @David E Speyer which is now deleted.